# Find inverse of $A(x) = x(t) + \int_{-\pi}^\pi x(t-s) \sin^2(2s)\,ds$ in $L_{2}[0, 2\pi]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A: L_{2}[0,2\pi]\to L_{2}[0,2\pi]$ be a linear operator defined with:
$A(x(t)) = x(t) + \int_{-\pi}^\pi x(t-s) \sin^2(2s)\,ds$.
We suppose that $x(t)$ is $2{\pi}$ periodic function.

How to find an inverse operator?

The logic we followed in the class is that you have to construct an equation system and use period. After that we solve that system with variables being $x(t)$ with different arguments and functions that contain $x(t)$. But that does not seem to be in this case because we can't combine $x(t-s)$ inside integral and $x(t)$ outside in different equations.

I tried to simplify $\sin^2(2s)$ but that didn't end up with anything useful.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Any $x\in L^2(0, 2\pi)$ can be decomposed as a Fourier series:
$$x(t)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} c_ke^{ikt}$$
Let's look at the action of $A$ on the Fourier basis. Using, for $k\geq 1$,
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{k(t-s)}\sin^2(2s)ds = \left \{ \begin{split}
&\pi &\text{ if } k=0\\
&-\frac{\pi}2e^{ikt}  &\text{ if } k=\pm 4\\
&0  &\text{ otherwise}
\end{split}
\right.\tag{1}$$
we obtain
$$Ax(t)=x(t)+\pi c_0 -\frac{\pi} 2 \left( c_4e^{4it} +c_4e^{-4it}\right)$$
So if you visualize $A$ as being an infinite matrix (its action on the Fourier basis), you have a diagonal matrix. The eigenvectors are the Fourier basis, the eigenvalues are all $1$, except for $\{1, e^{4it}, e^{-4it}\}$, for which the eigenvalues are $\{1+\pi, 1-\frac \pi 2, 1-\frac \pi 2\}$.

Inverting a diagonal matrix is easy. In this case, for any $y\in L^2(0,2\pi)$ with the following Fourier decomposition $y(t)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}d_ke^{ikt}$,
$$\begin{split}
A^{-1} y(t)&=\left(\sum_{k\neq \{0,4, -4\}}d_ke^{ikt}\right)+\frac 1 {1+\pi}d_0 +\frac 1 {1-\frac \pi 2}d_4e^{4it} +\frac 1 {1-\frac \pi 2}d_{-4}e^{-4it}\\
&= \left(\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}d_ke^{ikt}\right)-\frac \pi {1+\pi}d_0 + \frac 1{1-\frac\pi 2}\frac{\pi} 2d_4e^{4it} +\frac 1{1-\frac\pi 2}\frac{\pi} 2d_{-4}e^{-4it}\\
&=y(t)-\frac \pi {1+\pi}d_0-\frac 1 {1-\frac \pi 2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}y(t-s)\sin^2(2s)ds+\frac{\pi}{1-\frac \pi 2}d_0
\end{split}$$
where we have conveniently used $(1)$ again to rewrite the $d_4$ and $d_{-4}$ terms a convolution with $y$. Note that this has generated an extra $d_0$ term, which we can now group with the one we already had.

Finally, noting that $d_0=\frac 1 {2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}y(s)ds$, we conclude that $$A^{-1}y(t) = y(t)+\frac{6\pi^2}{(1+\pi)(2-\pi)}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}y(s)ds -\frac 1{1-\frac \pi 2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}y(t-s)\sin^2(2s)ds$$
I'm not great at computing, so you might spot a few mistakes here and there. But you get the general idea.